# Undefined control sequence error in \cite when compiling

Tags: bibtex

This is the start of the .tex file :

```
\documentclass{llncs}  
\newcommand{\modelName}{ABC}  %This is the name of the model  
\title{XYZ}  
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}  

Believable non-playable characters are critical to creating an immersive character-rich game world whether it is for entertainment or training \cite{reilly1996believable}.

\bibliographystyle{splncs}
\bibliography{aiide2014mx}
```

I am getting the following error with the above line. If anyone has any idea about this it would be really helpful! I do have the entry for the citation in the bib file. So I am not sure why I am getting this error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\b@reilly1996believable ->\citeauthoryear
{Reilly}{1996}
l.90 ...nt or training \cite{reilly1996believable}
. Emotionally plausible ch...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The .bib file is:

```
@techreport{reilly1996believable,
Author = {Reilly, W Scott},
Date-Added = {2014-05-13 05:53:57 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-05-13 05:53:57 +0000},
Institution = {Defense Technical Information Center (DTIC) Document},
Title = {{Believable Social and Emotional Agents.}},
Year = {1996}}
```

Comment: Just curious: why do you use the bibliography style `splncs.bst`? Springer's LaTeX package -- which may be obtained as a zip file at [Information for Authors of Computer Science Publications](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) -- currently provides `splncs03.bst`. I experience no problems compiling your MWE when using `splncs03`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your kernel file is not updated. This is how the following output results. Go to [Springer](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0/) and download the zip file `llncs2e.zip` then extract llncs.cls into your working directory.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{llncs}  
\newcommand{\modelName}{ABC}  %This is the name of the model  
\title{XYZ}  
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}  

Believable non-playable characters are critical to creating an immersive character-rich game world whether it is for entertainment or training \cite{reilly1996believable}.

\bibliographystyle{splncs}
\bibliography{aiide2014mx}
\end{document}
```